# How to remove a object from a data class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to remove a object from the list and so that i can add just required string and pass it . i have a model class like this

```
data class TagItem(
  val tagTittle: String,
  val isSelected: Boolean
)
```

this data class is mapped for the Lazy Column for making the list select and deSelect the items

```
 var tagsItems by remember {
                  mutableStateOf(
                      (tagsList).map {
                          TagItem(
                              tagTittle = it,
                              isSelected = false
                          )
                      }
                  )
              }

              val productEveryTags = tagsItems.filter {
                    it.isSelected
                }

                Log.i(TAG,"Only this $productEveryTags ")

                viewModel.onEvent(ProductUploadEvent.EnteredProductTags(productEveryTags))
```

i am filtering the selected items alone but in my log statement

```
Only this [TagItem(tagTittle=Tagged , isSelected=true), TagItem(tagTittle=Ducati , isSelected=true)]
```

How can i remove the "isSelected" object and just get the "tagTittle" alone into a single List

Comment: You want to _remove it from the class_ or just _not have it printed in this particular case_?

Comment: If you just want a list of the title strings:  `productEveryTags.map { it.tagTittle }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply map your instances for the output:

```
Log.i(TAG,"Only this ${productEveryTags.map { it.tagTittle }}")
```

Or combine it with the existing filter. Depending on whether you are interested in duplicates, you can also directly map to a set:

```
val productEveryTags = tagsItems.filter {
        it.isSelected
    }.mapTo(LinkedHashSet()) {
        it.tagTittle
    }

Log.i(TAG,"Only this $productEveryTags")
```